# How to solve: $x+\ln(x^2-1)=0$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I'm trying to solve the following equation for a couple of hours with no success.

$x+\ln(x^2-1)=0$

I'm trying to find x.

I tried playing with logarithmic identities to transform it to something simpler, but it didn't lead me to an answer.

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a solution, by intermediate value theorem. but I cannot find it analytically.

Comment: Use a numerical method, i.e. Newton-Raphson.

Comment: @GitGud I updated the question to make it clearer. I'm looking for x.

Comment: @Einat Ok, I deleted my comment. I don't think there's a way to find $x$ unless you do it numerically, that is, find an approximate value for $x$.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I think it should be e^x = 1/(x^2-1).

Comment: See the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A201940).

Comment: Introducing the lambert W I arrive at $ x=W(x/(x^2-1))$ ... but still only in the form of a fixed-point formula...

Answer (score 1):

Taking the easy route here:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%2Bln%28x%5E2%E2%88%921%29%3D0

There is no analytic solution. (Or else, Wolfram Alpha would get it)

Comment: Are you sure [Wolfram Alpha](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279372/a-limit-wrong-using-wolfram-alpha) would get it?

Comment: Yes, like 99.999% sure. Similar equations pose no problem and result in an analytic solution.

Comment: and how exactly did you rearrange it to $x^2 e^x = -1$?

Comment: Ähhmm ... by mistake. I should get some sleep...

Answer (score 1):

The above equation gives:

$$e^x=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$$

I suppose you know the graph of $f(x) =e^x$,now if you know how to draw the graph of $g(x) =\frac{1}{x^2-1}$ using its derivatives then, the value of $x$ corresponding to the point of intersection of the two curves on both sides of equality is the required value of $x$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $e^{-x}$?

Comment: thanks for notifying my error.

Answer (score 1):

Set $f(x)=-\ln(x^2-1)$ then we ask for its fixpoint $x = f(x) = f(f(x)) = ... $ . Someone proposed to use Newton/Raphson, and although I think it is the perfect one (because of its rate of convergence), here is a simpler iterative method.

**a) guess some range for a possible solution:** To have the log having a positive argument, a positive x must be greater than 1, but then to have the log negative (so that -log(...) is positive as x) x^2-1 must be smaller than 1, so x must be somewhere in the range $1 \ldots \sqrt2 $

**b) do iteration:** Now with some initial value for $x_0$ from this range, say $x_0=1.1$ iterating $x_{k+1}=f(x_k)$ diverges quickly. Thus we must find the inverse function to $f(x)$ which is $$g(x)=\sqrt{\exp(-x)+1}$$
Then we get the solution simply by initializing $x_0=1.1$ and iterating $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$ and $x=\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k$